# Font problems Futura Condensed Medium with ios 4.3

Tags: ios, fonts

Problem with ios 4.3 to display font "Futura Condensed Medium" as it works fine with ios 5.0

Any one having idea for this ios 5.0 v/s 4.3 problem??

Thanx in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the font "Futura-CondensedMedium" was not bundled in iOS 4.

Handy site for seeing iOS 4/5/6 fonts: [iOSFonts.com](http://www.iosfonts.com/)

Apple's documentation for fonts bundled in:

- iOS 4 → Unable to locate official list.
- [iOS 5](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4980)
- [iOS 6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484)